# PHP Output is a string instead of the string from another variable

Tags: php, string, variables, authentication, output

I am making for myself a script that checks how many mH/hash of my miners on mining pool websites are. Therefor I have a bunch of variables with $user and $pass for each site. Example:

```
   $user1 = 'A';
   $pass1 = 'B'

   $user2 = 'C';
   $pass2 = 'D';
```

So I made a PHP curl that login the form and checks the currently mH/hash.
Also I've made a counter, to rise the variable user1 and pass1 up by +1.

```
   $count = 0;
   $count = $count + 1;
   $user = "&#36;user$count";   
   echo $user;
```

But the problem is my output at the login form:

```
  $user2
```

Should be:

```
  C
```

I hope it is clear what I am looking for and thanks in advance.

Comment: A) Read the manual for ["variable variables"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), b) use arrays instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array. Start with something like:

```
$users = array(
    array('A', 'B'),
    array('C', 'D')
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo "Username: ".$user[0]. "\n";
    echo "Password: ".$user[1]. "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks gonna change my code into an array, sounds to be better indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Var concatenation is not very "recommended", but...

```
$user = ${'user'.$count}
```

You should consider using an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Array:

```
$user = [];
$pass = [];

$user[1] = 'A';
$pass[1] = 'B'

$user[2] = 'C';
$pass[2] = 'D';

$count = 0;
$count = $count + 1;
echo $user[$count];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a better approach to specify your user and password pairs in an array:

```
$login_info = array();
$login_info[] = array(
  'name' => 'A',
  'pass' => 'B',
);
$login_info[] = array(
  'name' => 'C',
  'pass' => 'D',
);
```

And you can travers the array by foreach:

```
foreach ($login_info as $info) {
  $name = $info['name'];
  $pass = $info['pass'];
  ...
}
```

You can easily add new elements to the array without creating new variables.